# Can I rename my project and associate an already-bound-to-another-project-Windows Store app with it?

Tags: windows-8, refactoring, windows-store-apps

I have a project (call it projectA) which is already associated with an as-yet unreleased Windows store app. I started a second project (call it projectB) which was meant as a "sandbox" for testing/experimenting/playing around (kind of a rogue/shadow projectA), but it turns out projectB has morphed into the "real" project.

Would I be in for a lot of headaches if I changed projectB's name to something more sensible (right now it's "MetroSandboxPlaypen")?

In a perfect scenario, I'd like to change its name and then associate it with the Windows store app I've already set up and connected with projectA. Is this possible? If so, do I first need to break the connection between projectA and my reserved Windows Store app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate any app with a Store application that has already been defined.  All you need to do is use the **Store - Associate App with the Store** command in VS.

This will pull down the Package Display Name, Package Name, Pub ID, and Pub Display name and configure your package manifest appropriately.

Comment: So if I've already associated a different project with the store, doing so again will replace the old with the new?

Comment: Correct.  The relationship between the Store and a project is really just the identifiers.  Until you submit the actual app package, there is nothing really "out there" so you can change it.